# Why isn't electron builder returning a .pkg file?

Tags: javascript, electron, app-store-connect, electron-builder, electron-packager

so I'll keep it short. I've been following this tutorial: https://www.techandstartup.org/tutorials/release-electron-app-on-mac-app-store

However as you'll see we need a pkg file to be uploaded to Transporter for App Store Connect. But when I run 'electron-builder' command I only get an 'Application' .I don't get any .dmg files or .pkg file. This is how my .plis looks like `

```js
{
  "name": "APPP",
  "productName": "APPP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder --mac"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "ME",
    "email": "ME@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^17.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
    "electron-packager": "^15.5.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.APP",
    "productName": "Frost",
    "buildVersion": "1.0.0",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2022 Developer or Company Name",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.Productivity",
      "icon": "/Users/alex/frost/src/icon.icns",
      "target": "dmg",
      "hardenedRuntime": false,
      "entitlements": "/Users/alex/frost/entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "/Users/alex/frost/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
      "provisioningProfile": "/Users/alex/frost/AppleDevelopment.provisionprofile",
      "type": "development"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

`